# The [social] tag has been burninated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [social](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/social) tag has the following description:

> The term social refers to a characteristic of living organisms as applied to populations of humans and other animals.

This clearly has nothing whatsoever to do with programming, not to mention being quite ambiguous. Can we get rid of this tag?

Comment: All, or some of it, is also copied directly from Wikipedia. For example, the second paragraph of sub section *"[Modern_uses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social#Modern_uses)"* in Wikipedia article *[Social](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social)* (starting with *"The social domain is often also contrasted"*).

Comment: It's for tagging posts about [tag:social] [tag:media]. Seems several people thought it was a good idea to tag their posts [tag:share] [tag:social] [tag:media] even.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

From a skim through the first couple pages, for the vast majority of these questions, the tag adds no useful information whatsoever.

I think there are two categories of questions where it might add *some* useful information:

- Questions about sharing functionality, especially built-in browser/OS share options: these should be retagged [web-share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-share), [android-sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-sharing), [ios-sharesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-sharesheet), etc., or [sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharing) if no more-specific tag exists.
- Questions about integration with social media in various ways, such as social sharing plugins or social media logins: the [social-media](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/social-media) tag seems to be a better fit for these, but the usage guidance on it could use some improvement.

For everything else, I'd say the tag should just be removed.

Comment: I'm not keen on the [tag:sharing] tag either.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Hmm, good point, it's kind of a mess too.  Maybe it'd be better to retag to [tag:web-share], [tag:android-sharing], [tag:ios-sharesheet], etc.  Edited to improve guidance.

Comment: On top of that, that tag wiki is probably plagiarized.

Comment: @Cerbrus: [It is](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410740/im-feeling-rather-antisocial-today#comment859975_410740)

Comment: I don't even like the use of 'sharing'.  When I upload a pic from my phone, I am NOT sharing it, despite what my annoying 'incompetent user friendly' phone says.  I am making a COPY of the data on a server, I am not sharing one pic!  [rant over]

Comment: It might also be useful applied to some agent-based models.

Comment: @pjs Could you give a couple examples of those?  Perhaps we could come up with a less-likely to be misused tag name for those, if there is indeed value there.

Comment: @MartinJames Wasn't the original name "send to" or something of the sort? Iconography would suggest so.

Comment: @RyanM I'm retired now, but in a prior life I saw an international effort to study which factors affect radicalization using agent-based modeling.  The researchers included sociologists who tried to identify which social interactions increased/decreased radicalization in a particular society. One of the interesting findings was that the culture being modeled was heavily patriarchal, but the societal respect for mothers was such that sons would not join a radical group without their mom's approval.  Influencing the moms was easier than convincing the teenage boys. Sounds social to me.

Comment: @RyanM Another agent-based model I saw was a study of exit strategies for large crowds from a constrained space. It involved who wants to stick together, how likely people are to wait, to shove, or to panic under various circumstances, and how the design of the egress points could favorably influence safe and speedy exiting.

Comment: I'm not advocating in favor of the `social` tag, just saying I see at least one area where it could be legitimately used in addition to the ones you brought up.

Answer (score 13):

[social](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/social) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Some questions relate to sharing systems related to a browser or OS; see [Ryan's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/410741) for guidance on these
- Questions about Apple's Framework [Social](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/social) should be retagged [social-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/social-framework)
- Most questions may not need a replacement tag at all, provided they're on-topic and otherwise good questions

## Progress:

The [social](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/social) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=social),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsocial%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsocial%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsocial%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsocial%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Track the progress of burnination

- [Progress tracker](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=410740)
- [Coordination chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244740/burnination-hq)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [social](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/social) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [social](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/social) tag—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [social](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/social) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.